# Embedding MyBB on a webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm trying to embed a MyBB forum on the *Forum* page on https://www.tourettestalk.co.uk. Other than using an iframe, is there a way of embedding the forum and making it just look like content?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the approach of having, for example, the forum in another domain or address. In the link, when clicking the user would go to that domain.

And yes, to embed another site on a webpage, I only know the iframe option. Another problem that you will have with the iframe, is having little space to navigate in the forum.

Comment: Ideally, I wanted to keep my design across all the pages.

Yeah, this is something that I thought would be an issue. I'll have to use a separate page for the forum.

Comment: Well, you can then customize the layout of the forum to have the same design. You can keep, for example, the same header and footer in both, and only content is what changes.

Comment: Yeah, I'll take a look at doing that I think. Thanks for your help mate.